# Script focusing on wrong email

Tags: vba, outlook

Below is a script I cobbled together from a number of other sources. It fires each time a new email arrives through an email rule in Microsoft Outlook 2013.

The script should look at the incoming email and strip out the page background.

What's happening is I get the popup saying new mail has arrived, and it will strip out the background of the email that was the focus in Outlook.
If I click on an email with an html background so that it is the focus of the preview pane and then receive a new email, it will remove the background of that focused email.

I want it to check the newly arrived message.

```vb
Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    MsgBox "Mail message arrived: " & Item.Subject
    Call ClearStationeryFormatting
End Sub
    
Sub ClearStationeryFormatting()
    On Error GoTo ClearStationeryFormatting_Error
    Dim strEmbeddedImageTag As String
    Dim strStyle As String
    Dim strReplaceThis As String
    Dim intX As Integer, intY As Integer
    Dim myMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    
    ' First, check to see if we are in preview-pane mode or message-view mode
    ' If neither, quit out
    Select Case TypeName(Outlook.Application.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set myMessage = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set myMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("No message selected.")
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Sanity check to make sure selected message is actually a mail item
    If TypeName(myMessage) <> "MailItem" Then
       MsgBox ("No message selected.")
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Remove attributes from <BODY> tag
    intX = InStr(1, myMessage.HTMLBody, "<BODY", vbTextCompare)
    If intX > 0 Then
        intY = InStr(intX, myMessage.HTMLBody, ">", vbTextCompare)
        strReplaceThis = Mid(myMessage.HTMLBody, intX, intY - intX + 1)
    End If
    
    If strReplaceThis <> "" Then
        myMessage.HTMLBody = Replace(myMessage.HTMLBody, strReplaceThis, "<BODY>")
        strReplaceThis = ""
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 7, , "An unexpected error occurred searching for the BODY tag in the e-mail message."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Find and replace <STYLE> tag
    intX = InStr(1, myMessage.HTMLBody, "<STYLE>", vbTextCompare)
    If intX > 0 Then
        intY = InStr(8, myMessage.HTMLBody, "</STYLE>", vbTextCompare)
        strReplaceThis = Mid(myMessage.HTMLBody, intX, ((intY + 8) - intX))
    End If
    
    If strReplaceThis <> "" Then
        myMessage.HTMLBody = Replace(myMessage.HTMLBody, strReplaceThis, "")
    End If
    
    If InStr(1, myMessage.HTMLBody, "<center><img id=", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        strEmbeddedImageTag = "<center><img id="
        '"<center><img id=""ridImg"" src="citbannA.gif align=bottom></center>"
        intX = InStr(1, myMessage.HTMLBody, strEmbeddedImageTag, vbTextCompare)
        If intX = 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 8, , "An unexpected error occurred searching for the embedded image file name start tag in the e-mail message."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        intY = InStr(intX + Len(strEmbeddedImageTag), myMessage.HTMLBody, " align=bottom></center>", vbTextCompare)
        If intY = 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "An unexpected error occurred searching for the embedded image file name end tag in the e-mail message."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        strEmbeddedImageTag = Mid(myMessage.HTMLBody, intX, intY - intX)
        intX = InStr(1, myMessage.HTMLBody, "<CENTER>", vbTextCompare)
        intY = InStr(intX, myMessage.HTMLBody, "</CENTER>", vbTextCompare)
        strReplaceThis = Mid(myMessage.HTMLBody, intX, intY - intX) & "</CENTER>"
        myMessage.HTMLBody = Replace(myMessage.HTMLBody, strReplaceThis, "", , , vbTextCompare)
    End If
    
    ' Finally, saved modified message
    myMessage.Save
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
    
    ClearStationeryFormatting_Error:
    
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry that the script seems to break in and out of the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass the mail item you want to process as a parameter, i.e.

```
Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   MsgBox "Mail message arrived: " & Item.Subject
   ClearStationeryFormatting Item
End Sub

Sub ClearStationeryFormatting(myMessage As Outlook.MailItem)
    On Error GoTo ClearStationeryFormatting_Error
    Dim strEmbeddedImageTag As String
    Dim strStyle As String
    Dim strReplaceThis As String
    Dim intX As Integer, intY As Integer

    ' Remove attributes from <BODY> tag

    '...
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply and also reformatting the original post. I've made this exact change, but strangely it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've removed the case switching and now it works perfectly! Thanks for input :-)